# Three points are collinear if and only if the matrix has a non trivial solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to prove three points are collinear iff$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1&y_1&1&0\\x_2&y_2&1&0\\x_3&y_3&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$has a non-trivial solution. I'm having problems on the $\Leftarrow$ side. I assumed that if$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1&y_1&1&0\\x_2&y_2&1&0\\x_3&y_3&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$has a non-trivial solution, then it has infinite solutions. Therefore, I can find a solution in which the points are collinear. But my thought process seems very fishy to me. I'm sure I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: To be precise: an *equation* can have a nontrivial solution. A matrix cannot; it does not make sense for a matrix to have a solution. What you mean is that the equation $$\begin{pmatrix}x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\ x_3 & y_3 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$ has a nontrivial solution $(a,b,c)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that the equation $$\begin{pmatrix}x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\ x_3 & y_3 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$ has a nontrivial solution $(a,b,c)$. Then all three points $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, and $(x_3, y_3)$ lie on the line $ax + by + c =0$.

Comment: This is, by far, the simplest and most direct of the answers given.

Answer (score 1):

The points $A(x_1, y_1), B(x_2, y_2), C(x_3, y_3)$ are collinear if the determinant of the matrix is equal to zero.

$$\begin{vmatrix}x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\ x_3 & y_3 & 1\end{vmatrix} = 0$$

Note that this is because we can calculate the area of a triangle by
$$A=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \begin{vmatrix}x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\ x_3 & y_3 & 1\end{vmatrix}$$
As the points represent the vertices of the triangles, if the area exists, the determinant must be different from zero, otherwise, the vertices are aligned, and therefore, collinear.

You may also take this example using vectors. Once two vectors $\vec v$ and $\vec u$ are collinear if $\exists k \in \mathbb{R}: \vec v=k\vec u$, two vectors are collinear if they are parallel.

Given the points $P(3, 2, 1)$, $Q(-2, 5, 2)$ and $S(8, -1, 0)$,

$\overrightarrow {PQ} = Q - P = (-2, 5, 2)-(3, 2, 1)=(-5, 3, 1)$

$\overrightarrow {QS} = S -Q = (8, -1, 0)-(-2, 5, 2)=(10, -6, -2)$

Once $-2 \overrightarrow {PQ}=\overrightarrow {QS}$, we have  $\overrightarrow {QS}\parallel\overrightarrow {PQ}$ and hence $P, Q$ and $S$ are collinear.

Comment: My favorite way of proving the determinant area formula is to *start* from the fact that the points are collinear when the determinant is $0$. Then, we can check that both (signed) area and the determinant vary linearly as we move one of the points along a line. Then, we figure out that the constant of proportionality, $\frac12$, by checking a special case.

Answer (score 0):

Geometriclly seen, the area enclosed between three points in 3-space vanishes when the determinant

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\ x_3 & y_3 & 1\end{pmatrix} = 0 $$

It is same as saying that these three points and vectors connecting them are collinear.